# WPF ListView throws exception whenever I change items in it

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, listview

So I have been having this problem for several days now, where I have a simple ListView item that gets filled up dynamically. The user can add to a list entries which should show up on the display. This works, however when I try to do anything with the listView Items, either delete or even refresh them, I get a NullReferenceException. Please take a look at the code below.

The XAML file (snippet):

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,97,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Names" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding documentName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And here is a snippet from the .cs code:

```
public class Entry {
  public string documentName {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string languageAssistantName {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string assignmentDate {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string deadline {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string progress {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string supervisorName {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string remarks {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string proofread {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public Entry(string documentName, string assignmentDate, string deadline, string supervisorName, string remarks, string LAName, string progress, string proofread) {
    this.documentName = documentName;
    this.assignmentDate = assignmentDate;
    this.deadline = deadline;
    this.supervisorName = supervisorName;
    this.remarks = remarks;
    this.languageAssistantName = LAName;
    this.progress = progress;
    this.proofread = proofread;
  }
}

List < Entry > entryList = new List < Entry > ();

private void UpdateListView() //This is the code that adds the new entries to the listView, this works
{
  listLabel.Text = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < entryList.Count; i++) {
    listLabel.Text += i + " | " + entryList[i].ToString() + "\n\n";
    listView.Items.Insert(0, entryList[i]);
  }
}

/*This is the part that throws exception

*/
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  listView.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

I have tried this with SelectedItem, Refresh, ItemsSource and everything else I could think of :/ . Every time I try to remove anything from the list, I get NullReferenceException. And the worst is that it doesn't actually show me a line where the error occurs, so I'm assuming it's something out of my control. But when I tried to fix .Net framework, it said nothing was wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Just bind `ListView.ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<Entry>` and add/remove items from the collection. You're reinventing a square wheel here.

Comment: Your way of coding looks like WinForms. If you use WPF, it is best to forget about and not do it like you would with WinForms. Look into how WPF utilizes data binding to present whatever data/content/state in the UI...

Comment: Binding it to an ObservableCollection<Entry> was actually the very first thing I tried, same problem there. I could add to it very nicely, but didn't let me remove or change anything.

Comment: Do you display any data? Can you see actual data?

Comment: Do you mean if I know that I actually have data inside my list? I know that the list works correctly, I can print out everything, even the listView.SelectedItem.

Comment: @gogo199432 Can you share the code where you call the RemoveAt method of the ObservableCollection (not ListView.Items) and it throws an exception? What was in the stack trace?

Comment: Your code works fine as long as there are still items in the ListView. No exceptions until it throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when I try to delete from an empty listview.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so apparently I was an idiot. I didn't know that Visual Studio actually refuses to show the location of the error if I'm launching my project in 'Release' instead of 'Debug'. So after switching that back, I found out that the error was completely unrelated to listView.

Apparently in the 'Equal' operator of the Entry class, the p object was sometimes null. Now I still don't know where that comes from, but after adding an extra if statement, everything works wonderfully.

Thanks for the help anyway :)